# Export Sql membership data to asp.net identity 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, sqlmembershipprovider

I am updating my MVC application to use asp.net identity, is there any way to import current users information from Sql-Membership Provider.

Comment: Yes you can, manually. There is no automated tool from Microsoft for it.